# in R summarizing data and add different mutate

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summary

I'd like to finally summarize my data after the data cleaning.

Here is my data structure:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("01002", 
"01004", "01005", "01006", "01009", "01011"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(17645, 17645, 17645, 17646, 17646, 17646, 
    17646, 17646, 17646, 17646, 17648, 17646, 17648, 17646, 17648, 
    17646, 17646, 17646, 17649, 17646), class = "Date"), category = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
    2L, 5L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", 
    "Q"), class = "factor"), level = c(3000, 3000, 1000, 1000, 
    1000, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 8000, 9999, 
    9999, 9999, 300, 300, 300, 9999)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
dataDF %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(category) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(n = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(percentage = (prop.table(n))*100) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

with the following result:

```
  category     n percentage
  <fct>    <int>      <dbl>
1 A            4         20
2 C            4         20
3 G            4         20
4 Q            4         20
5 B            2         10
6 D            1          5
7 F            1          5
```

Now I'd like to add a new column with an aggregation of the date.

I need to add for each category the mean counted dates per ID.

Here is how the data should look like (random numbers, not calculated).

```
  category     n percentage mean_reported_days_per_ID
  <fct>    <int>      <dbl>    <int> 
1 A            4         20     2
2 C            4         20     3.4
3 G            4         20     4
4 Q            4         20     1
5 B            2         10     3.5
6 D            1          5     2
7 F            1          5     1.1
```

I'm not sure how that could be achieved. I tried to add another mutate() and calculate the mean days per ID and add it (with another group by) to the data table.

thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You want average unique dates per ID for each category?

You just need to group and summarise twice:

```r
require(dplyr)

dataDF %>% 
  group_by(ID, category) %>%
  summarise(distinctDates = n_distinct(date)) %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(mean(distinctDates))
  
#   category `mean(distinctDates)`
#   <fct>                    <dbl>
# 1 A                         1.33
# 2 B                         1   
# 3 C                         1   
# 4 D                         1   
# 5 F                         1   
# 6 G                         1   
# 7 Q                         1
```

If you want to join those values to your existing DF, just do
`left_join(your.existing.df, this.new.df, by = "category")`

Comment: Yes, I want average unique dates per ID for each category. I will try it! thx.